# getting feeds to update in Managing News 1.2 (Drupal 7 distribution)

Tags: drupal-7

I am attempting to create a half decent substitute for Google Reader but am running into a problem: when I first set up the distribution named in the title I was able to add a bunch of feeds which were displaying as hoped for (most recent posts first).

My assumption was that every time I visited the site, the RSS feeds would update and show any new content. However, the only content displayed is that which was new the day I added the feeds.

How can I address this? I notice that if I add a new feed, all the other feeds update to their newest content, if this helps put my problem in context.

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeds are fetched during creation and [cron](https://drupal.org/cron) run in managing news distribution.

So try [setting up cron](https://drupal.org/node/23714) jobs properly.

Also make sure the feeds that you are fetching has new contents ( by manually inspecting the feed xml).